# BufferedImage does not appear in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, bufferedimage, paintcomponent

This is my second java project, I am totally new to programming but I have been working on this for quite a while now. However the code could be a mess. I am attempting to reproduce an Image in a JFrame, but I have no idea how to resolve the stated problem. Could it be the fault of the file format?
When I insert the package folder and the image file as a path, it compiles without an error message, even though it seemingly doesn't draw anything. After I changed the path to my Desktop (or really anything else) I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at Informatik.Timezones.main(Timezones.java:287)
```

Apparently the source is not found, which means it was correctly recognized before. Perhaps I am drawing on the JFrame instead of a Label or Panel and this causes the problem.

Here is the part of the code in the main method which generates the Panel and draws the image.

```
    JFrame zeichnen = new JFrame(); 
    face = new JLabel();
    face.setVisible(true);
    face.setSize(1000, 1000);
    face.setLayout(null);
    face.setLocation(0, 0);
    zeichnen.add(face);
 
    zeichnen.setVisible(true);
    zeichnen.setSize(1000, 1000);

    zeichnen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    zeichnen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    zeichnen.setResizable(false);
    zeichnen.setLayout(null);
    

    
    try {
        bildchen =                                                                                  ImageIO.read(Timezones.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Info      rmatik/a.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my reprex:

```
package Informatik;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.*;




public class Test extends JPanel{


static JLabel face;
static BufferedImage bildchen; 

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics maler) {
       super.paintComponent(maler);
     
       Graphics2D maler2 = (Graphics2D) maler;
       maler2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      maler.drawImage(bildchen, 1000, 1000, null);
}
      
    public static void main (String args []) {

    JFrame zeichnen = new JFrame(); 
    face = new JLabel();
    face.setVisible(true);
    face.setSize(1000, 1000);
    face.setLayout(null);
    face.setLocation(0, 0);
    zeichnen.add(face);

    zeichnen.setVisible(true);
    zeichnen.setSize(1000, 1000);
    try {
        bildchen = ImageIO.read(Timezones.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/Informatik/a.jpg"));
     } catch (IOException e) {
        //catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    zeichnen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    zeichnen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    zeichnen.setResizable(false);
    zeichnen.setLayout(null);
    }
}
```

Here's the new, working version:

```
package Informatik;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.print.DocFlavor.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestImageLoad extends JPanel {

JLabel face;
BufferedImage bildchen;

TestImageLoad() {
initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
JFrame zeichnen = new JFrame();
face = new JLabel("face");
face.setForeground(Color.RED);
zeichnen.add(this);
this.add(face);

try {
    java.net.URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/Informatik/a.jpg");
    System.out.println(url);
    bildchen =   ImageIO.read(url);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
zeichnen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
zeichnen.pack();
zeichnen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
zeichnen.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics maler) {
super.paintComponent(maler);
maler.drawImage(bildchen, 0, 0, this);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
Runnable r = () -> {
    new TestImageLoad();
};
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
}
}
```

Comment: Your override looks missplaced, you need to override it the JFrame you weanna show

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos what do you mean exactly? I don't think I can place the Override notation elsewhere

Comment: *what do you mean exactly?* - custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of  JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame. Also, you are trying to draw the image at (1000, 1000) which may be outside the bounds of the panel so you won't see the image. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). Download the working example and customize is to paint an image instead of display text. The class is better structured than your example.

Comment: The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use Icons` which will show you the proper way to read an image.

Comment: Well, i looked into it, but it doesn't seem to be related to bufferedImage, and that's where the problem probably lies. and I believe I did not really understand the part about overriding the paintComponent() of JPanel. Isn't that what I have already done?

Comment: what does `IllegalArgumentException: input == null!` mean? is it in some way meaningful? Just for the record: When I declared the variable i wrote: `Static BufferedImage bildchen = null;` And there the error message also mentions `Unknown Source`.

Comment: Try to change `Informatik/a.jpg` to `/Informatik/a.jpg`.

Comment: @George Z. No, same situation.

Comment: @LoremIpsum1729 Then the image is not under directory `/Informatik/`. Or it is not named `a.jpg`. This error means that image cannot be found. Do some experiments with its path.

Comment: I ruled out both of these things. and also tried out getResource(); none of these work

Comment: @George Z. i even tried out `right click on the project name -> Properties-> Java Build Path-> Source Tab` and changing source folder rules

Comment: @LoremIpsum1729 Create a [mcve] then.

Comment: @George Z. Done. I somehow posted it as an "answer".

Comment: @LoremIpsum1729 Then delete it, and edit the question.

Comment: @George Z. should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

**Comments on new (working) code**

Class loaders are handy things for loading application resources, but there are a few tricks to getting them to work correctly:

(But first a personal aside) I avoid the `getResourceAsStream` method for a variety of reasons. Primary among them are:

- `getResource` returns an `URL`. It's easier to debug when this goes wrong, as we can print out the URL and check it points where we *think* it should. If the resource was not found, it will be `null`, but it can also warn when we have two identically named resources in the class-path and it is not fetching the one we want. The latter is pretty rare, but it does happen.
- If we need an `InputStream` from the URL, it is but a single method call. Easy. OTOH many methods work better (or even only) with a `URL` or (a `String` that represents) a `File` etc. or a `BufferedInputStream` (that applies to Java Sound particularly, possible other things) and the stream returned from the `getResourceAsStream` method is typically not buffered. Again, it is but a single line of code to fix that, but it can trip us up. And if the method takes an URL, that is all handled automatically.
- They use different rules for finding resources. This seems like an idiotic decision by Sun/Oracle, but .. whatever. I typically advise people to prefix the path with `/` to ensure they are going directly from the root of the class-path. That works fine with `getResource`, but .. differently with `getResourceAsStream`. To be honest, people have tried to explain the intricacies of the differences, but I tune out. `getResource` works and that's what I use.

OK, now I've explained why I advised to use `getResource`, back into the tricks.

1. Well, you'd already used one, mentioned above. Namely by adding `/` as a prefix.
2. But most importantly, the difference between the **root** and **context** class loaders. I had uncountable troubles trying to fetch a resource within the `main` method (setting an icon for the host `JFrame`). It turned out that the call was using the system or root class loader which is only intended to load system (e.g. the JRE API classes) resources. It has a very limited class path in order to make searches faster. The **context** class loader is the one on which our embedded resources can be fetched. But a call like `TimeZone.class.getClassLoader()` will generally fetch the root class loader, not the context. To get the context class loader, it always works of the code is called from the constructor or a method of our custom class, and using an instantiated object (like `this`).

**Old Code**

The original code added the label to the frame, but not the custom painted panel that drew the image! The way to do it would be to add the custom painted panel to the frame, then add the label to that panel.

The original code was a mess. I reorganized it and fixed many things while doing so. So many things I've forgotten what. Instead refer to this code for details.

First check this code works on your system / environment, then get ***this code*** to work with ***your image***, which still seems to be a problem.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestImageLoad extends JPanel {

    JLabel face;
    BufferedImage bildchen;
    
    TestImageLoad() {
        initUI();
    }
    
    private void initUI() {
        JFrame zeichnen = new JFrame();
        face = new JLabel("face");
        face.setForeground(Color.RED);
        zeichnen.add(this);
        this.add(face);

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg");
            bildchen = ImageIO.read(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        zeichnen.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        zeichnen.pack();
        zeichnen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        zeichnen.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics maler) {
        super.paintComponent(maler);
        maler.drawImage(bildchen, 0, 0, this);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            new TestImageLoad();
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems to work, but the problem with the image not displaying still persist. (At least when I try to fetch it from a file on my pc, which is the way I wanted it to work.)

Comment: Edit this code into the question, but change the bit where you try to load the image from the class path. I'll look further into it.

Comment: Okay, changed the line.

Comment: Try masking a new project, copy/pasting that altered code into it, and compiling it. Report back.

Comment: BTW - use `getResource` rather than the `AsStream` version. Separate out the code into 3 lines, 1) `URL url = this.getClass().getResource(..)` 2) `System.out.println("URL: " + url);` 3) `ImageIO.read(url);`. I have several reasons for suggesting this change, too long to go into in a single comment.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot. It does the job when splitted into three parts. I tried `getResource()` before but it didn't seem to work. Anyways I am still curious why it works now

Comment: Can you show the **exact** code used as an edit to the question?

Comment: I made an edit to my answer to go into the .. quirks .. of class loaders. Does that explain why I advised as I did?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Which part do you not understand? Now is a good time for more, rather than less, words.

Comment: what do you mean by "to go into the quirks of class loaders"?

Comment: Did you read the new bits in my answer between **Comments on new (working) code** and **Old Code**. Well, them. I meant them.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I blindly skipped them. What exactly are root and class loaders in layman's terms?

Comment: and one last question: why doesn't the window show up when i export it as a jar file?

Comment: *"What exactly are root and class loaders in layman's terms?"* Well .. *"the system or root class loader .. is only intended to load system (e.g. the JRE API classes) resources. It has a very limited class path in order to make searches faster. The context class loader is the one on which our embedded resources can be fetched."* .. as I wrote in the edit to the answer. Again, if there is something in that text you do not consider to be at 'layman' level, then please be more specific. Do you notice how I'm typing more in comments than you? Try to shift that balance, as it gets pretty tiresome..

Comment: .. to type replies 'playing 20 questions' to drag relevant information from someone we're sacrificing our time, for free, to try and help.

Comment: ok, well i will have to read  up on class paths a bit...the rest is clear